# Remover uma linha específica em todos arquivos de um diretório usando PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um diretório com 5500 arquivos nomeados de forma aleatória sem extensão, por exemplo:

- 4as6d4ad
- 4asd564ad
- 1mi3jh
- 019i43nmasf

Preciso remover a última linha de todos arquivos neste diretório. Encontrei [este código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17381793/8635788) mas não consegui adaptá-lo:

```
<?php 

// load the data and delete the line from the array 
$lines = file('filename.txt'); 
$last = sizeof($lines) - 1 ; 
unset($lines[$last]); 

// write the new data to the file 
$fp = fopen('filename.txt', 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, implode('', $lines)); 
fclose($fp); 

?>
```

O código acima funciona, mas tenho que especificar arquivo por arquivo.

**Edit:** Com a ajuda do nos comentários, consegui resolver o problema utilizando:

```
<?php 
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

// load the data and delete the line from the array 
$lines = file($entry); 
$last = sizeof($lines) - 1 ; 
unset($lines[$last]); 

// write the new data to the file 
$fp = fopen($entry, 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, implode('', $lines)); 
fclose($fp); 


        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: [Listar todos os arquivos do diretório](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php) e fazer essa alteração que funciona em um loop não funcionaria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

// load the data and delete the line from the array 
$lines = file($entry); 
$last = sizeof($lines) - 1 ; 
unset($lines[$last]); 

// write the new data to the file 
$fp = fopen($entry, 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, implode('', $lines)); 
fclose($fp); 


        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: +1 - Quando puder, marque como aceita (após o prazo do sistema).

Comment: Só uma sugestão, melhor seria gravar num arquivo separado (ou com outra extensão) pois se rodar acidentalmente 2x vai tirar 2 linhas. Sempre que fizer este tipo de trabalho, evite modificar sobre o original